# How to get an array of dates of weekends following an input date from the same month with one formula in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How do you get an array of dates of weekends following an input date from the same month with one formula?

Input is any (Google Sheet) date serial that is not at the end of a month. For example

**Input**:

| A |
| --- |
| Mar 30 |

Note: `A1` has a manual input of `Mar 30`, which results in the date serial for Mar 30, 2024 since 2024 is the year this question is posted.

**Desired**:

|  |
| --- |
| Mar 31 |

**Input**:

| A |
| --- |
| Mar 20 |

Note: same as earlier

**Desired**:

|  |
| --- |
| Mar 23 |
| Mar 24 |
| Mar 30 |
| Mar 31 |

**Input**:

| A |
| --- |
| 8/22/2024 |

**Desired**:

|  |
| --- |
| Aug 24 |
| Aug 25 |
| Aug 31 |

---

A working formula will be used ~10-100 times in a sheet. Thus lightweight solution is preferred but not required.

---

###### Re: using iteration

An answer using iteration would be helpful. Nevertheless, it is preferred if non-iterative solution can be found. The reason is that this is not for my personal sheet. If I need to turn iteration on in the setting, then in practice, the solution to the problem has two parts: 1) the formula, 2) the setting toggle. Unwitting users of the resultant sheet may attempt to re-use the solution by creating a new sheet (ie. without the setting) and copy-pasting the formula, which would break an iterative solution without realizing how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```cpp
=FILTER(A1+ROW(1:30),REGEXMATCH(TEXT(A1+ROW(1:30),"dddm"),"S.."&MONTH(A1)))
```

[image]

Generates a list of 30 consecutive dates starting from the day after A1 and it only keeps the Saturdays / Sundays of the month of the date in A1.

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution 1

```js
=let(input,A1
    ,eom,eomonth(input,0)
    ,dayNum,weekday(input)
    ,numSat,floor((eom-input+if(dayNum=7,0,dayNum))/7)
    ,numSun,floor((eom-input+dayNum-1)/7)
    ,if(numSat+numSun=0,,arrayformula(input
         +sort(vstack(if(numSat,sequence(numSat,1,if(dayNum=7,7,7-dayNum),7),tocol(,3))
                     ,if(numSun,sequence(numSun,1,8-dayNum,7),tocol(,3)))
              ,1,true)))
```

##### Explanations

This is a forward counting version of **Solution 2** below, which we will explain in detail. Understanding one should mean understanding the other.

The other difference between the 2 solutions is that with **Solution 1** we generate a sequence representing the day difference of future Saturdays within the month and similarly for future Sundays, as opposed to generating date serials directly. One benefit of using regular numbers is that the output array will carry the formatting of the input. Another benefit is that we are able to use `sequence`. `sequence` is faster than `makearray` but the downside is that we need to use it twice (and then concatenate with `vstack`) and then `sort`.

For <100 calls, performance won't come into play. Nonetheless, using `sort` adds a lot of overhead, probably comparable to the rest of the formula.

Both methods need to check 0 length when making arrays because Google Sheet built-in functions (sadly - *very*) do not support cases that output empty arrays.

Both methods are lightweight because we calculate the appropriate days directly using the `weekday` number and end-of-month date of the input -- once, without using `filter` or any other built-in function to check `month` and `weekday` on date serials again, which are extra calculations, both heavier than the calculations we build into the formulas in these 2 solutions.

---

#### Solution 2

```js
=let(input,A2
    ,format,"mmm d"
    ,eom,eomonth(input,0)
    ,if(input=eom,"???"
                 ,let(
     dayNumSinceSun,weekday(eom,1)
    ,lastSunday,eom-dayNumSinceSun+1
    ,lastWeekendIsSat,dayNumSinceSun=7
    ,numDays,lastSunday-input
    ,numWeekends,floor(numDays/7)*2+min(2,mod(numDays,7))
    ,vstack(if(numWeekends=0
              ,tocol(,3)
              ,makearray(numWeekends,1
                        ,lambda(i,j,let(diff,numWeekends-i,dateSerial
                                       ,if(iseven(diff),lastSunday-diff/2*7
                                                    ,lastSunday-(diff-1)/2*7-1)
                                       ,text(dateSerial,format))))
           ,if(lastWeekendIsSat,text(eom,format),tocol(,3))))))
```

---

##### Explanations

We will find the weekends of the same month as the input date by identifying the last weekend of the month.

Below is a sequence of steps to get to that and then how to use it. There are a good number of steps, each step using result of the previous. But each step is small and simple.

- **Last day of the month**

```js
=let(input,A2
    ,eomonth(input,0))
```

We use `let` to progressively build our function *as well as* centralizing the use of input variable to one place -- at the beginning.

- **Weekday number of the last-day-of-the-month**

```js
=let(input,A2
    ,eom,eomonth(input,0)
    ,weekday(eom,1)
```

- **Last Sunday of the month**

```js
=let(input,A2
    ,eom,eomonth(input,0)
    ,dayNumSinceSun,weekday(eom,1)
    ,eom-dayNumSinceSun+1)
```

- **Date of last weekend of the month**

```js
=let(input,A2
    ,eom,eomonth(input,0)
    ,dayNumSinceSun,weekday(eom,1)
    ,lastSunday,eom-dayNumSinceSun+1
    ,lastWeekendIsSat,dayNumSinceSun=7
    ,if(lastWeekendIsSat,eom,lastSunday)
```

(*We will use last Sunday as the reference point later. So we won't need last weekend per se. The above outputs date of last weekend for illustrative purpose.*)

- **Number of weekend days from the input date to last Sunday**

```js
=let(input,A2
    ,eom,eomonth(input,0)
    ,dayNumSinceSun,weekday(eom,1)
    ,lastSunday,eom-dayNumSinceSun+1
    ,lastWeekendIsSat,dayNumSinceSun=7
    ,numDays,lastSunday-input
    ,numWeekends,floor(numDays/7)*2+min(2,mod(numDays,7)
    ,numWeekends)
```

The number of weekend days from input day to end-of-month will be a key input for building the desired output array.

There are several ways to get this number. One way is by locating the last Sunday of the month. If there are n whole weeks and m extra days outside whole weeks between input date and the last Sunday, then there are n*2 + min(2,m) weekend days between input date and the last Sunday. Since we are using last Sunday as the reference point, we will store the number of weekend days between input and last Sunday.

Once we know the number of weekend days that need to be displayed, we can use `makearray` to build the desired output array.

If we first make an array to print all weekends from after the input date to the last Sunday, then in this array, the date of last Sunday will be printed last.

- **The date the *i*th row should carry**

In order to determine the date the *i*th row should carry, it is conceptually simpler to base it on how far *i* is from the ending index, which we have from earlier in `numWeekends`.

```js
=let(diff,numWeekends-i                               
    ,if(iseven(diff),lastSunday-diff/2*7
                    ,lastSunday-(diff-1)/2*7-1)
```

`diff` is the distance to last row. What date we print depends on whether it should be a Saturday or a Sunday. Hence even/odd `diff` branching.

- **Appending the last Saturday, if applicable**

Using `vstack`,

```js
vstack(...,if(lastWeekendIsSat,eom,tocol(,3))
```

The only way a Saturday from within the month can follow the last Sunday of the month is by being the last day of the month. Hence, in the `if` branching, we use end-of-month if that is the case, and empty otherwise. Empty is encoded as `tocol(,3)`.

- **Add formatting**

If particular formatting is desired, it is possible to directly format with Google Sheet's built-in formula. For example,

```js
text(...,"mmm d")
```

displays month_name by 3 letters, followed by space, and day in 1 digit if possible, 2 digits otherwise. We name the formatting string at the beginning of the formula in order to highlight the inputs at the beginning. (Everything that follows is program logic which a user does not need to touch.)

Formatting the whole column manually using the Google Sheet UI is perfectly valid as well.

Finally, putting everything together, and add an input validation `if`, you have the answer at the beginning.

---

*By the way, the granularity of the individual steps helps making/debugging the final function. Similar to helper functions in programs we write in other languages, the more of them, the easier to debug, and to extend functionality.*

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response! The answer works for any of March 2024 dates but doesn't work for `8/2/2024`, for example, missing the last Saturday. Could you take another look please?

Comment: @DZ: Aye. See edit.

Comment: Great. Thank you! Solution 1 works for all the test cases on my end. Solution 2 seems to fail on dates that are not followed by weekends within the month. (It errors out on Apr 29, 2024.) I appreciate the explanations under Solution 2 nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

- Calculate the `NET` `WORK` ing `DAYS` between `s`tart date and `E`nd `O`f the `MONTH`, considering `w`eekend`s` as Monday to Friday. This gives the `n`umber of real weekends(Sunday/Saturdays).
- Create a `SEQUENCE` of numbers using the `n`umber of days from the above step and pass it to `WORKDAY`  to get the next `SEQUENCE` of working dates

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  LET(
    ws, "1111100",
    s, A1,
    n, NETWORKDAYS.INTL(s+1,EOMONTH(s,0),ws),
    WORKDAY.INTL(s,SEQUENCE(n),ws)
  )
)
```

##### Highly optimized:

- No unneeded arrays created or filtered
- No unnecessary calculations
- No text manipulations or regex
- Uses inbuilt functions to do the heavy work

Comment: Say my name!!!!

Comment: can you test for *Mar 30*; think it should be *NETWORKDAYS.INTL(s+1*

Comment: @rockinfreakshow You're right. Feel free to edit it directly.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The solution doesn't work for a number of days, including Apr 29 (error out) and Aug 17 (prints extra Sept 1). Would you be interested in checking those cases? I'd appreciate it. For the purpose understanding performance, `NETWORKDAYS.INTL` and `WORKDAY.INTL` both require doing several daytime arithmetic on the date serials right? So they are equivalent as using `filter` to check `month()` and `weekday()` right?

Comment: @Snoozy  See latest edit by rockinfreakshow. Apr29 should error out as there are no more weekends(If you want, you can handle that with `IFERROR`). Aug 17 would be fixed now. In general inbuilt functions are faster than frakensteined/externally crafted filter or month/weekday functions.

Comment: @TheMaster: I see. I can definitely handle it with `iferror`. I just wasn't sure because the `filter` based solutions would give "No matches are found in FILTER evaluation." error message and since `filter` is the outer most function, it is obvious immediately that the error correlates to the no more weekend case.

Answer (score 1):

A filter based solution:

```js
=let(input,A1
    ,arr31day,arrayformula(input+sequence(30))
    ,dayNum,arrayformula(weekday(arr31day,2))
    ,iferror(filter(arr31day,month(arr31day)=month(input),dayNum>=6)))
```

This does require generating extra dates, which is fast. But to conveniently check their month and weekday number, and thus apply `filter` without doing the calculation on calendar days ourselves, we use `month()` and `weekday()`, which in turn requires some more calculations in the backend. But overall it should not impact your sheet's responsiveness if you are only using the formula <100 times.